# Why does $\bar{t_n}-{T_n}=\frac{3}{4^{k_n}}$

Tags: decimal-expansion

We have that $$t=0_4.q_1q_2q_3... \in [0,1]$$ t is in Quaternary form.

Let $$T_n=0_4.q_1q_2q_3... q_{k_{n-1}}0$$ and

$$\bar{t_n}=0_4.q_1q_2q_3..q_{k_{n-1}}3$$

Why does $\bar{t_n}-{T_n}=\frac{3}{4^{k_n}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a\in[0,1)$ has the following form in base $b$
$$
a=0.a_1a_2\cdots a_n
$$
The above notation is just short-hand for
$$
a=\sum_{j=1}^na_jb^{-j}
$$
So in your case
$$
T_n=\sum_{j=1}^{k_{n-1}}{q_j\over4^j},\quad \bar t_n=\sum_{j=1}^{k_{n-1}}{q_j\over4^j}+{3\over4^{k_{n-1}+1}}
$$
If $k_n=k_{n-1}+1$, the above equations immediately yield the desired result.

Comment: Where did you get b from?

Comment: @Aljabra $b$ is an arbitrary base. In your case $b=4$.

Comment: How did you know this? Is there some sort of book you could recommend? I am really struggling with this topic.

Comment: @Aljabra Let me think, I'll get back to you with a recommendation:)

Comment: Thank you. That would be great, The topic I am looking at is space filling curves and I dont understand the derivation in the Hans Sagan book.

Comment: @Aljabra You're struggling with representation of numbers in different bases. I didn't find what I expected to but [read this](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/18) to understand how natural numbers are represented in different bases and [1st page of this](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS00/19504-V/Chapter1.pdf) to understand how real numbers are represented in different bases (don't read beyond page 1). Lastly read the worked examples [here](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maxmr/analysis1/Pickering_EDITED_FINAL.pdf). Nothing explains better than examples.